# Are the free Win 7/8/10 VM's Microsoft provides for testing purposes restricted or any different than their counterparts?

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtual-machines

Sorry for the poor title, I'll explain better here. Microsoft provides free Win 7/8/10 Enterprise VM's inorder to test modern browsers here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

I want to use the OS for something different than testing websites on browsers, for testing some software I wrote. But I don't know if the VM Microsoft provides is restricted in features or is different than its vanilla counterpart (a regular Win 7 OS you license)

I looked at the 'Microsoft Software License Terms for the IE VMs' briefly but couldn't see any sections that outlined differences

Comment: The OP is not asking about licensing (which is explicitly stated as being for evaluation only); he's asking whether the VMs are functionally equivalent to their full counterparts, or are somehow stripped down.

Comment: Yes, I am asking what Massimo said

Comment: "*Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported [..] software platforms [..] may not be suitable for Server Fault*" and "*Questions must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. [..] questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.*" - you want to use an unsupported test tool, outside its license agreement (which is for non-commercial use anyway); this isn't reasonable IT management practice. Way off topic :P

Comment: In my experience, they work fine with other apps. The main restriction on them is they have a 30 day ticking time bomb - the install will stop working after that. Take a snapshot before you start it the first time to be able to reset that counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To learn more about those VM too on my side, I asked your question on a private channel I have with MS and from a well known IE MVP I got this answer;

> There are no limits and they are not stripped down.

nb. **Limit** for using the VM for testing anything, not for the actual activation limit.

Comment: Well, that's clearly not the case. "Please note that these virtual machines expire after 90 days" is a limit.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can revert the snapshot so limits doesn't bother me. I am looking for possibly stripped down parts. Also I'd accept this answer but I can't really verify the legitimacy :/

Comment: @ceejayoz **Limit** was told for testing other stuff than IE, not the **time limit**

Comment: @yagmoth555 Well for any future users that stumble across the question they cannot verify it for themselves. Maybe let a moderator know the proof? Il accept the question if no other answers are made a bit later

Comment: @BDillan All of the answers are correct. There are no functionality limits ... unless the evaluation period runs out.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally there are no restrictions on the system / OS.  They do, however, maintain the usual evaluation licensing restrictions -- meaning they are for short-term, test use only.  If you're going to do anything long-term or production based, you'll need to get the appropriate licensing.

Answer (score 1):

The VMs are not restricted. You can install whatever software you like provided it's compatible with the operating system.

I have used these frequently to test out Group Policy in labs, testing deployment of software in SCCM, and for testing programs I've written on multiple platforms.